# Name error in one program whereas syntax error in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

So at first, I needed to create a program where the user enters a Character and if that is Int then an error should pop up... if its Str then it should further divide into Consonants and Vowels. However, this wouldn't solve the problem (and it wasn't working) as the user could enter special characters which would just filter out as Consonants

```
Z = (input("Enter a character: "))
if type(Z) == int:
   print(Z, "is a numeral")
else: 
   if (Z=='A' or Z=='a' or Z =='E' or Z=='e' or Z=='I'or Z=='i'
        or Z=='O' or Z=='o' or Z=='U' or Z=='u'):
      print(Z, "is a Vowel")
   else:
      print(Z, "is a Consonant")
```

So, after this, I tried to create a list which has all the alphabets in it, and then I thought it would work ... I was wrong

```
my=input('Enter a character:')
list=[a,A,b,B,c,C,d,D,e,E,f,F,g,G,h,H,i,I,j,J,k,K,l,L,m,M,n,N,o,O,p,P,q,Q,r,R,s,S,t,T,u,U,v,V,w,W,x,X,y,Y,z,Z]
if my in list:
   if (my=='A' or my=='a' or my=='E' or my=='e' or my=='I'or my=='i'
        or my=='O' or my=='o' or my=='U' or my=='u'):
      print(my, "is a Vowel")
   else:
      print(my, "is a Consonant")
else:
    print ('HAHAHA')
```

This shows this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\veert\Desktop\Python\VowelOrConsonant#1.py", line 2, in <module>
    list=[a,A,b,B,c,C,d,D,e,E,f,F,g,G,h,H,i,I,j,J,k,K,l,L,m,M,n,N,o,O,p,P,q,Q,r,R,s,S,t,T,u,U,v,V,w,W,x,X,y,Y,z,Z]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Please help me guys

Comment: Please add each character inside " ". Otherwise, python interpreter try to search variables like a, A, b, B, .... etc. That's why the NameError occurs

Answer (score 1):

The above list value should be type String. So you need to add every character inside "" as below.

```
my=input('Enter a character:')
list=["a","A","b","B","c","C","d","D","e","E"]
if my in list:
   if (my=='A' or my=='a' or my=='E' or my=='e' or my=='I'or my=='i'
        or my=='O' or my=='o' or my=='U' or my=='u'):
      print(my, "is a Vowel")
   else:
      print(my, "is a Consonant")
else:
    print ('HAHAHA')
```

When you add list = [a, A, b, B, .... ], Python interpreter try to search value of that variables a, A, b, B etc. It is not pre-defined here. So, it return that NameError.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
 vowels = ['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u'],
 consonants = ['B','b','C','c','D','d','H','h','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','V','v','W','w','X','x','Y','y','Z','z']

inp = input('Please enter a character > ')

if inp not in vowels and inp not in consonants:
    print(f'{inp} is not in the alphabet')

if inp in vowels:
    print(f'{inp} is a vowel')

if inp in consonants:
    print(f'{inp} is a consonant')
```

I've separated vowels from consonants trying to shorten the comparison operators to only a few for readability.

Cater for all input:

```
alphaneumeric = {
    'vowel': ['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u'],
    'consonant': ['B','b','C','c','D','d','H','h','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','V','v','W','w','X','x','Y','y','Z','z'],
    'number': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'],
    'symbol': ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','[',']','{','}','<','>','.',',','\'','"',':',';','-','=','/','\\','~','`']
}

inp = input('Please enter a chacter > ')

for key, lst in alphaneumeric.items():
    if inp in lst:
        print(f'{inp} is a {key}')
        break # return immediately
```

Comment: Man thank you ... I'm new to python so this completely slipped my mind ... Thanks so much

Comment: No problem :)  We should make this better by outputting immediately when the element is found. Instead of traversing the list to the end, even after finding the element.

If you print(key) during the loop, you will see that the element is found, but the loop will continue after the print(f'{inp} is a {key}') is found. An easy way to achieve this would be to add 'break' after the comparison operator, which checks 'if inp in lst'.

Comment: Hint: `import string` and `str.lower`.

Comment: @tobias_k sound advice sir, the OP must definitely look into the string module.